# How to Change Font Size of Text in ListField?

Tags: blackberry

In `drawListRow()` method, I draw texts using `graphics.drawText()`. How can I change the font size of text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your ListFieldCallback code, override drawListRow() and set the Font there:

```
public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y, int w) {
    Font myFont= FontFamily.forName(FontFamily.FAMILY_SYSTEM).getFont(fontStyle,
        fontSize);
    g.setFont(myFont);
    g.drawText(str, 0, y, DrawStyle.TOP|DrawStyle.LEFT, w);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried first setting the `Graphics#setFont` with your newly sized font?

Perhaps using `Font#derive(style, size)`:

> http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/Font.html#derive(int,%20int)

Just quickly perused the javadocs, not actually done this. something like:

> font myFont8 = ...;
>
> Font myFont16 = myFont8.derive((myFont8.getStyle(), 16);
>
> g.setFont(myFont16);
>
> g.drawText(...);